# usea savePreferences in dynamically layout -android

Tags: android, layout, save, preferences

I'm making an app that contains a dynamically layout and it generates textView's in run time, I need that when I close the application all the textView has been added, don't erase; I think I can do that whit savePreferences(), but What parameters I have to use?

```
private void savePreferences(What parameter here, What parameter here) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor edit = sp.edit();
        edit.commit();
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preferences should work. Try this...

```
public class sample extends Activity {
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
   super.onCreate(state);
   . . .

   // Restore preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
   setSilent(silent);
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();

  // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
  // All objects are from android.context.Context
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

  // THIS IS WHERE YOU STORE THE TEXTVIEW DATA
  // THERE ARE MANY '  editor.put...(...) ' methods 
  // ie. editor.putInt(...) , editor.putString(...)
  editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

  // Commit the edits!
  editor.commit();
}
```

}